# why google.com redirects to google.co.in

Tags: dns

Have you seen that Google.com is not opening, can anyone tell what is the reason behind that. if you search Google.com in India then it automatically redirects to Google.co.in 
I need technical answer (may be in terms of dns means complete flow analysis). 
also, i know google.com/ncr will open google.com but why it redirect to local server. what the basic flow behind that????

pls help if anyone can??? any comment or any other link is apperciated...

Also what is the difference between fqdn/realm/domain????

Answer (score 9):

When you connect to the HTTP servers that serve Google.com, it will determine your country from your IP address, then send an HTTP 302 status code that redirects you to the appropriate domain name.

Visiting `google.com/ncr` will set a cookie that `google.com` checks for to prevent the redirect.